# dhtmlx scheduler adding custom inputs

Tags: forms, scheduler, dhtmlx

Is there any possibility to add a custom input form on dhtmlx scheduler such as text, select, texarea, etc.

Because i desire to add my custom items on it like  etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can add any number of predefined inputs or implement a custom ones, check these articles
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/custom_lightbox_editor.html
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/lightbox_editors.html

You can also redefine the details form completely, as described here
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/custom_details_form.html